# Adding and Updating data by month in Access with Vb.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net, date, ms-access

I've been trying to add and update data to a table in MS Access by month. This is so I can calculate any expenditures or sales per month. So if stock for a company were bought in March It would add this to the March expenditure row. And would be kept different from the expenditure in February or April for example.

I am unsure how to do this and how to have my program check the current month and year to see where it should input the data/make a new row for the month.

I know how to write to a database, I'm just not sure how to make my program write to a row in the database that depends on the current month and year

Any help would be greatly appreciated and sorry If this is all long winded or this is an easy fix, its my first post here and I'm a novice when it comes to programming.

Answer (score 0):

In Access, to get the current date you use the `date()` function. I.E. if you were to do:

```
SELECT DATE()
```

the query would return the system date, which, today would be:

```
26/03/2015
```

To do math (add or subtract a specified interval) against the date, the syntax, again in Access, is:

```
DATEADD([Interval],[Number],[Date])
```

So, if I wanted to add one month to the current date I would write:

```
DATEADD(m, 1, DATE())
```

Or conversely, subtract two months from the current date:

```
DATEADD(m, -2, DATE())
```